# Color Scale formatting depending on column-based data

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I format a multi-columns table with a 3 color scale formatting depending on the percentiles (red:percentile(0,20), yellow:percentile(0,5), green:percentile(0,8) ) of each column ?

[image: Here is what I want]

For this example I had to make the same conditionnal formating twice (once for each column). I want to know if there is a way to make one conditionnal formating for both columns.

Thank you